# Wordle clone in Python

Tags: python, game, wordle

I spent some time making a simple Wordle clone in Python. The word bank consists of all words of a specified length taken from nltk's Brown corpus. I would appreciate any advice or criticism to improve my program's coherence and efficiency.

```
import random
import re
from nltk.corpus import brown
from termcolor import colored

allowed_attempts = 6
word_length = 5
word_bank = [word.upper() for word in brown.words() if len(word) == word_length and word.isalpha()]

def validate(attempt, answer, current_alpha):
    result = ''
    for pos, char in enumerate(attempt):
        if char == list(answer)[pos]: # Letter is correct and in right position
            result += (' ' + colored(char, 'green') + ' ')
            current_alpha = current_alpha.replace(char, (colored(char, 'green')))
        elif char in answer: # Letter is correct but in wrong position
            result += (' ' + colored(char, 'yellow') + ' ')
            current_alpha = current_alpha.replace(char, (colored(char, 'yellow')))
        else: # Letter is incorrect
            result += (' ' + char + ' ')
            current_alpha = current_alpha.replace(char, (colored(char, 'red')))  
    print('\n' + result + '\n')
    return current_alpha

def guess(answer):
    alphabet = ('\n\n   Q  W  E  R  T  Y  U  I  O  P   \n    A  S  D  F  G  H  J  K  L    \n      Z  X  C  V  B  N  M     \n\n')
    print('\nEnter your ' + str(allowed_attempts) + ' guesses. \n')
    for i in range(allowed_attempts):
        while True:
            print(alphabet)
            attempt = input('Attempt #' + str(i + 1) + ': ').upper()
            if len(attempt) == word_length and attempt in word_bank: # Ensures user input is valid
                break
            else:
                print(colored('\nNot in word bank.', 'red'))
        if attempt == answer: # Checks if user won
            return True
        else:
            alphabet = validate(attempt, answer, alphabet)
    return False
    
def main():
    print('\n\n\nI am thinking of a ' + str(word_length) + '-letter word. Can you guess in ' + str(allowed_attempts) + ' tries? \n')
    print('If a letter is in the right place, it will be ' + colored('green', 'green') + '.\n' +
    'If it is in the word but in the wrong place, it will be ' + colored('yellow', 'yellow') + '.\n' +
    'If it is not in the word, it will be ' + colored('red', 'red') + '.\n')
    while True:
        answer = random.choice(word_bank) # Picks a word for this turn
        if guess(answer):
            print(colored('\nCongratulations! You won!\n', 'green', attrs=['bold']))
        else:
            print('\nYou lost! The word was ' + colored(answer, 'green') + '\n')
        if input('\nWant to play again with a new word? Type anything to keep playing, or type Q to quit. ').upper() == 'Q':
            print('\nThanks for playing.\n')
            exit()

main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very good code overall! Just some improvements that came to mind:

#### What if the data is not yet downloaded

If the corpus is not yet downloaded the code will crash, you should do instead:

```
import nltk
try:
    word_bank = [word.upper() for word in brown.words() if len(word) == word_length and word.isalpha()]
except RuntimeError: # data is not yet downloaded.
    nltk.download(brown)
    word_bank = [word.upper() for word in brown.words() if len(word) == word_length and word.isalpha()]
```

#### Remove repetition

In this `if` `else` chain the only thing changing is the color so:

```
    if char == list(answer)[pos]: # Letter is correct and in right position
        result += (' ' + colored(char, 'green') + ' ')
        current_alpha = current_alpha.replace(char, (colored(char, 'green')))
    elif char in answer: # Letter is correct but in wrong position
        result += (' ' + colored(char, 'yellow') + ' ')
        current_alpha = current_alpha.replace(char, (colored(char, 'yellow')))
    else: # Letter is incorrect
        result += (' ' + char + ' ')
        current_alpha = current_alpha.replace(char, (colored(char, 'red')))
```

becomes:

```
    if char == list(answer)[pos]: # Letter is correct and in right position
        color = 'green'
    elif char in answer: # Letter is correct but in wrong position
        color = 'yellow'
    else: # Letter is incorrect
        color = 'default' # or white or black
    current_alpha = current_alpha.replace(char, colored(char, color))
```

So it is clear that the if else is only deciding the color.
Even better would be to return a data structure [ (character, guessing_level), ...] for simpler testing and debugging and then go from the data structure to a pretty output.

#### Constant UPPERCASE

Just a useful convention in Python.

```
allowed_attempts = 6
word_length = 5
```

should be uppercase.

#### Small user friendlyness improvement.

```
    if input('\nWant to play again with a new word? Type anything to keep playing, or type Q to quit. ').upper() == 'Q':
```

should be:

```
    if input('\nWant to play again with a new word? Type anything to keep playing, or type [q]uit to quit. ').upper().startswith('Q'):
```

So that if the user types "quit" it also works.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great! No idea how I overlooked the repetition in that validation function, this is so much better. I'm going to go implement these changes now. As a relative beginner, I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 6):

Couple of more improvements you can make:

---

You could make `word_bank` into a set, for \$O(1)\$ containment testing:

```
WORD_BANK = {word.upper() for word in brown.words() if len(word) == word_length and word.isalpha()}

...
            if attempt in WORD_BANK:
                ...
```

Since the `WORD_BANK` only contains 5-letter words, testing the length of the word is unnecessary.

You can't use a `set` in `random.choice`, so you'd need to convert it to a list for the initial word selection, but that is once-per-puzzle instead of once-per-guess lookup. `answer = random.choice(list(WORD_BANK))`  Alternately, store the word bank as both a list and a set.

---

Ranges can start at 1, eliminating the need for `+ 1` calculations inside the loop.  You can combined this with `f'...'` strings, and eliminate the explicit call to `str(i + 1)`:

```
    for attempt_number in range(1, allowed_attempts + 1):
        ...
            attempt = input(f'Attempt #{attempt_number}: ').upper()
```

There are other places you could used f-strings, like:

```
    print(f'\n\n\nI am thinking of a {word_length}-letter word. Can you guess in {allowed_attempts} tries?\n')
```

---

## Bugs

If the secret word is `BURNT` and I guess `TOAST`, it is going to claim the first `T` is in the wrong spot, and the last `T` is in the right spot.  The real Wordle would ignore the first `T` because the last `T` is in the correct spot and there are no other `T`'s in the answer.

Your `alphabet` is will get longer and longer as letters are guessed in the correct and incorrect spots.   For instance, the `T` would become `"... Q W E R [yellow]T[normal] Y U ..."` after processing the first letter of the guess `[T]OAST`, and then the `T` would be again replaced when the last letter was processed `TOAS[T]`, resulting in `alphabet` containing:

`"... Q W E R [yellow][green]T[normal][normal] Y U ..."`

Successive guesses will continue to wrap the letters with additional ANSI codes.  A double letter in the answer might end up either green or yellow depending on the last match of that letter in the guess word.

---

## Design Flaw

The method `validate` is both displaying output and returning a value.  Functions should return a value or perform an action, not both.  If you were to change the game to have GUI, you could not reuse the `validate` function because it was printing output to a console.  You would have to rewrite it.

Returning two values is allowed.  The caller can print the `result` to the console or display it in the GUI, as appropriate.

```
def validate(...):
    ...
    return current_alpha, result

def guess(...):
    ...
        ...
        alphabet, guess_result = validate(attempt, answer, alphabet)
        print(f"\n{guess_result}\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for these great suggestions, I appreciate you taking the time! I hadn't even heard of f-strings before this, nor did I consider adding +1 to allowed_attempts in the loop range. I was aware of the BURNT/TOAST bug and have been struggling to find an efficient way to fix it. As for the alphabet problem, maybe it could be addressed by making the object a dictionary with the letters as keys and colours as values? Finally, I have noted the problem with the validate function and will apply your suggestion. Thank you again!

Comment: "_I was aware of the BURNT/TOAST bug_" ... in which case, the code really wasn't working as intended, and therefore not [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Code Review.  The "alphabet problem" could certainly be addressed using a dictionary mapping letters to colour; of course you'll have to solve the duplicate letter green/yellow issue first.